# A criterion for a ramification of an algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field.
Let $h$ be the class number of $K$.
Let $l$ be a prime number.
Suppose $l$ does not divide $h$.
Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of degree $l$.
Let $H$ be the [Hilbert class field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_class_field) of $K$.
Suppose $L/K$ is unramified.
Since $L/K$ is abelian, $L$ is a subfield of $H$.
Hence $l$ divides $h$.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $L/K$ is ramified.

**My Question**
Can we prove that $L/K$ is ramified without using class field theory?
In other words, can we prove the following proposition without using class field theory?

**Proposition**
Let $K$ be an algebraic number field.
Let $h$ be the class number of $K$.
Let $l$ be a prime number.
Suppose $l$ does not divide $h$.
Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of degree $l$.
Then $L/K$ is ramified.

Comment: If you’re asking for a proof of a proposition without use of CFT, I’d like a precise statement of the proposition.

Comment: @Lubin I added the precise statement to my question. Regards,

Comment: OK, thanks, that’s what I thought you might be asking. At first glance, it certainly does look fundamentally class-field-theoretical...

Comment: @Lubin It seems that Kummer proved the above proposition when $l$ is odd and $K$ is the $l$-th cyclotomic field.